# Can I switch grad schools early in MA?

Tags: graduate-school, graduate-admissions, masters

I am currently almost one semester into a graduate program at a school in Michigan.  However, I just heard back from my dream school in Florida. **Am I able to stop my program at one school and start at another?**  I don't even mind starting fresh seeing as I'm only 2 classes deep into my MA.  Any help/suggestions/opinions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What's stopping you?

Comment: @JeffE while I agree with your sentiment that there is no reason not to switch (especially from an MA program), I think it is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do whatever you want.  If another school accepts you into their program and you'd rather be there, I don't see a problem.  Of course, there exist circumstances in which switching might have downsides, but you haven't told us enough about your situation for any of us to judge them.  Sounds like you just want someone to tell you it's OK to switch, which I'm fine with doing.